# How to sort data from a database table based on following criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle

**Reference Table:-**

[image]

```
UserID  VideoID LikeType    Timestamp
1      1        Like            12/8/2018
1      3       DisLike          12/10/2018
2      5       DisLike          12/8/2018
2      2       DisLike          12/6/2018
2      3       DisLike          12/6/2018
3      1       Like             12/1/2018
3      2       Like             12/1/2018
3      4       Like             12/10/2018
```

In the above sample table, I want to know the most controversial video ( VideoID).
A controversial video is a video that has **almost** equal Likes and dislikes. That means users is not able to decide and have some controversial view about the video.

For example, In the above case -
Video 1 & 3 are most-watched ( considering every user must either like or dislike) while Video 2 is most controversial ( 1 Like and 1 dislike as users do not have unanimous votes on it)

**Answer reference** :-

I used the "Select INTO"  statement to create two new tables from the above - bifurcating them on the basis of Likes & Dislikes separately - but not sure how to fetch the data further?
Do you have any other method to do that
** **Please do consider the case when a video has 1,00,000 Likes and 99,0000 Dislike will also be considered as most controversial****

Answer (score 0):

This might be one option. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (userid, videoid, liketype)
  3     AS
  4        -- sample data
  5        (SELECT 1, 1, 'Like' FROM DUAL
  6         UNION ALL
  7         SELECT 1, 3, 'DisLike' FROM DUAL
  8         UNION ALL
  9         SELECT 2, 5, 'DisLike' FROM DUAL
 10         UNION ALL
 11         SELECT 2, 2, 'DisLike' FROM DUAL
 12         UNION ALL
 13         SELECT 2, 3, 'DisLike' FROM DUAL
 14         UNION ALL
 15         SELECT 3, 1, 'Like' FROM DUAL
 16         UNION ALL
 17         SELECT 3, 2, 'Like' FROM DUAL
 18         UNION ALL
 19         SELECT 3, 4, 'Like' FROM DUAL),
```

---

```
 20     temp
 21     AS
 22        -- summaries
 23        (  SELECT videoid,
 24                  SUM (CASE WHEN liketype = 'Like' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cnt_l,
 25                  SUM (CASE WHEN liketype = 'DisLike' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cnt_d,
 26                  --
 27                  COUNT (*) cnt
 28             FROM test
 29         GROUP BY videoid)
 30  -- most controversial video has ratio between 0.4 and 0.6 (that's just an example,
 31  -- set it to any values you want)
 32  SELECT videoid
 33    FROM temp
 34   WHERE     (cnt_l / cnt) BETWEEN 0.4 AND 0.6
 35         AND (cnt_d / cnt) BETWEEN 0.4 AND 0.6;

   VIDEOID
----------
         2

SQL>
```